# how to install a MQTT Broker on shared hosting server

Tags: php, shared-hosting, mqtt

"Really Small Message Broker" is an MQTT message broker, but I was wondering how could I install a RSMB on my shared hosting server with Justhost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like [it's a daemon written in C](http://www.alphaworks.ibm.com/tech/rsmb/download).  Unless you are permitted to run daemons on your shared hosting account (*very* unlikely), you're probably out of luck.

If you must remain on shared hosting, consider a web service like [Amazon Simple Queue Service](http://aws.amazon.com/sqs/).

If you really, really want to run this specific message queue, you'll probably want to move to a small virtual private server.

Comment: It's also important to understand the licensing behind RSMB - it is from IBM alphaWorks and not to be used in "production" environments.